# An issue with approximations of a recurrence sequence

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, taylor-expansion

By trying to give an approximation to a given recurrence sequence I encountered a problem.

To be more precise I have a method but it fails if the right condition is not met and I wonder how I should proceed then.

An example will clarity.

### General Question:

Let $a_0=c>0$ , $a_n=f(a_{n-1})$ and the sequence is strictly decreasing and has limit equal to $0$. Also for every finite $n$ we have $a_n >0$.

### Specific Example:

Let $f$ be the function $log(1+x)$.

THE NECC CONDITION :
$\dfrac{x^m}{f(x)}$ is analytic at $x=0$ for some integer $m$.

### Solution for the Specific Example:

**Step 1.** Since
$$0 < a_{n+1} = \log (1+a_n) < a_n,$$
it is a monotone decreasing sequence which is bounded. Thus it must converge to some limit, say $\alpha$. Then $\alpha = \log(1 + \alpha)$, which is true precisely when $\alpha = 0$. Therefore it follows that
$$a_n = o(1). \tag{1}$$

Before going to the next step, we make a simple observation: it is easy to observe that the function
$$\frac{x}{\log(1+x)}$$
is of class $C^3$. In particular, whenever $|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}$, we have
$$ \frac{x}{\log (1+x)} = 1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{12}+O(x^3). $$
This can be rephrased as
$$ \frac{1}{\log(1+x)} = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{12}+O(x^2). \tag{2}$$
Here, we note that the bound, say $C > 0$, for the Big-Oh notation does not depend on $x$ whenever $|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

---

**Step 2.**
By noting $(1)$, we fix a positive integer $N$ such that whenever $n \geq N$, we have  $|a_n| \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Then by $(2)$,
$$ \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{2} + O(a_n), $$
where the bound for Big-Oh notation depends only on $N$. Indeed, we may explicitly choose a bounding constant as
$$C'=\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{2}C,$$
where $C$ is the same as in $(2)$. Thus if $n > m > N$, we then have
$$ \begin{align*}
\frac{1}{a_n}
&= \frac{1}{a_{m}} + \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} \left( \frac{1}{a_{k+1}} - \frac{1}{a_k} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{a_{m}} + \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} \left( \frac{1}{2} + O(a_k) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{a_{m}} + \frac{n-m}{2} + O((n-m)a_m).
\end{align*} $$
Thus we have
$$ \left|\frac{1}{n a_n} - \frac{1}{2}\right| \leq \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{a_m} + \frac{m}{2} + C'm a_m \right) + C' a_m.$$
Taking limsup as $n\to\infty$, we have
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{1}{n a_n} - \frac{1}{2}\right| \leq C' a_m. $$
Since now $m$ is arbitrary, the right-hand side can be made as small as we wish. Thus the left-hand side must vanish, yielding
$$ \frac{1}{n a_n} = \frac{1}{2} + o(1),$$
or equivalently
$$ n a_n = 2 + o(1). \tag{3} $$

---

However notice how much that method depended on the NECC CONDITION , SINCE we needed a taylor series with nonzero radius when expanded from $0$.

So my question is what should I do if that NECC condition is not met for $f$ ?

*MORE SPECIFIC* How do I proceed for an $f(x)$ that is not meromorphic at $0$ but is meromorphic on the halfopen interval $)0,1/2)$ ?

I considered using the taylor expansion of $f$ at $\frac{1}{q}$ and taking the limit for large positive $q$ going to $\infty$. But Im not sure how to do that. Or even if its a good idea.

Im also unsure if it matters what type of singularty we have at $0$.

But I believe there must be a way!

*ONE MORE THING*

I assumed that $f$ has no natural boundary. Not sure if it matters or not.
Such as if $f(x)$ is defined for $x<0$ matters or not.

---

To end this question maybe a more specific question : ADD to the above question the condtion that $f(f(x)-x) - (f(x)-x) = g(x)$ where $g$ is the FUNCTIONAL INVERSE of an entire function.

Maybe that makes the question easier because it is more specific.

---

Comment: It is really, really hard to figure out the question you're asking here. Is there any way to make your post more concise and more focused?

Comment: How did you go from $\frac{x}{\log(1+x)}$ to class $C^3$?  I'm not sure what $C^3$ represents.  Was this arbitrary, or does it depend upon the absolute value of $x$, for example?

Comment: Matt : $C^3$ means the first 3 derivates are continuous. That is standard notation.
GregMartin : What do we do when the necc condition given in the OP does not hold ? That is what is asked for.

Comment: For instance suppose $f$ is given as in this recent question of me (link below) and is thus not analytic at 0 !
In that case the necc condition and method given in the OP do not work. Hence the question how to handle it. So I set a bounty on this question. I hope that clarifies for those confused. Here is the link about $f$ : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389888/how-to-formally-show-that-fz-is-analytic-at-z-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hence the question [is] how to handle it.

"It" corresponds to $a_0=c$ with $c\gt0$ and $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ for every $n\geqslant0$, where
$$
f(x)=\frac1{\frac1x+\log\frac1x}.
$$
Such a function cries out for conjugacy... Thus, let us consider the sequence defined by $b_n=1/a_n$, then $b_{n+1}=g(b_n)$ for every $n\geqslant0$, where
$$
g(x)=x+\log x.
$$
If $b_0\gt1$, that is, if $c\lt1$, then $(b_n)$ is increasing and $b_n\to+\infty$ hence $a_n\to0$. If $b_0=1$, that is, if $c=1$, then $b_n=a_n=1$ for every $n$. If $b_0\lt1$, that is, if $c\gt1$, then $b_n\lt0$ after a while hence $(b_n)$ is not defined.

Thus, the case of interest is $c\lt1$. Associated to $b_{n+1}=g(b_n)$ is the ordinary differential equation $x'(t)=g(x(t))-x(t)=\log x(t)$, solved by
$$
t=\int_{x(0)}^{x(t)}\frac{\mathrm du}{\log u}=\mathrm{li}(x(t))-\mathrm{li}(x(0)),
$$
where $\mathrm{li}$ denotes the logarithmic integral. Thus, $\mathrm{li}(x)\sim x/\log x$ and $x(t)\sim t\log t$ when $t\to+\infty$. This suggests, and indeed one can show, that $b_n\sim n\log n$ when $n\to\infty$.

More precisely, $\log t\geqslant\log b_n$ for every $t$ in $(b_n,b_{n+1})$ hence
$$
\mathrm{li}(b_{n+1})-\mathrm{li}(b_n)=\int_{b_n}^{b_{n+1}}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\log t}\leqslant\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{\log b_n}=1,
$$
that is,
$$
\mathrm{li}(b_n)\leqslant\mathrm{li}(b_0)+n.
$$
Likewise, $b_{n+1}-\log b_{n+1}\leqslant b_n$ hence $\log(t-\log t)\leqslant\log b_n$ for every $t$ in $(b_n,b_{n+1})$ hence
$$
\int_{b_n}^{b_{n+1}}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\log( t-\log t)}\geqslant\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{\log b_n}=1,
$$
that is,
$$
\int_{b_0}^{b_{n}}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\log( t-\log t)}\geqslant n.
$$
Since $\log( t-\log t)\sim\log t$ when $t\to\infty$, all this yields $\mathrm{li}(b_n)\sim n\sim b_n/\log b_n$, and finally,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\log n)a_n=1.
$$

Comment: What is the justification to go from a difference equation to a differential equation ?? I think this needs to be explained for "beginners" like me. Is it because ln is a slowly growing function ? I understand that the difference between an integral and the analogue sum can be bounded. But Im not convinced this means we can rewrite a difference equation into a differential equation. In fact , I think we cannot do so if we replace ln with exp.

Comment: *What is the justification to go from...* The explanation for beginners and the justification both begin with "More precisely". // *Im not convinced this means we can rewrite a difference equation into a differential equation*... Fortunately, nobody (at least, not I) said so (do you see such an assertion in my answer?).

Comment: Ok I meant associate instead of rewrite. If you cannot justify the association , how do you know your answer is correct ? btw I asked a new question related to this.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396456/when-is-it-justified-to-approximate-a-difference-equation-with-its-corresponding Here is the related question.

Comment: This is the second time you aggressively suggest that my answer is BS. As already indicated, the analogy with an ODE is not necessary to justify the results about the behaviour of the discrete dynamical system (although they definitely motivate it). If you failed to grasp this, first when reading my answer, and second when I recalled it in my comment, please learn to read.

Comment: Plz I do not suggest your answer is BS. My understanding is just not sufficient. You say the analogy with ODE is not neccessary , but then how does you justify using it ? Not trying to be difficult , I just do not get it. Hence I asked a new question about it.

Comment: Once again, learn to read: *how do[es] you justify using it?* Where do you see that the analogy was used? It was not. (To make your case worse, the alleged quote in the other question is a fabrication.)

Comment: Did , I gave you the bounty ! So stop pretending im hostile. Im just asking for clarifications for things that are unclear to me. Im not an expert so do not shoot at me or feel attacked.

Comment: @Did You are behaving very unreasonably. The OP is simply having difficulty trying to understand the logic of your answer; there is no need to abuse him. I will try and clarify the logic for mick.

Comment: @Sharkos Thanks for your analysis. I disagree with it, with reasons thank you. Good luck in your exchanges with this user (who, I suspect, will now try to show they can behave).

Comment: @mick: The idea is that, by thinking about the related ODE, we analyze the equation in a similar manner. As Did indicated, the paragraph "Associated to [...] This suggests, and indeed one can show, that $b_n\sim n\log n$ [...]" can be completely omitted from the answer. The statement about bounding functions using the logarithmic integral $\mathrm{li}(b_n)$ are exact and refer only to the sequence, not some DE. If you read these with a clean mind, you can derive the results without ever imagining the DE.

Comment: Thank you Sharkos but Im still puzzled.

Comment: All clear now. :)