# How to formally show that $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, inverse

Let $z$ be a complex number. Let $$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{z}+\ln(\frac{1}{z})}.$$ How to formally show that $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=0$?
I know that for small $z$ we have $$\left|\tfrac{1}{z}\right|>\left|\ln(\tfrac{1}{z})\right|$$ and that implies $|f(0)|=0.$
Are there multiple ways to handle this ?

Comment: It seems to me people need to think about a branch cut for $\log$. There's no way this function is defined for all $z$ in a punctured neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @mick: Can I know where you get this problem from?

Comment: @TLC : 
This (link below) is related and I gave a link there (to here).
There is also a closed question related.
There is a bounty on the question !
Link : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374726/an-issue-with-approximations-of-a-recurrence-sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, "analytic" means "locally represented by its Taylor series". With this interpretation $f$ is not analytic. Indeed, suppose $f(z)=z^r\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n $ in a neighborhood of $0$, where $c_0\ne 0$. Then 
$$\frac{1}{z}+\ln \frac{1}{z} = z^{-r} \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n $$ in some (possibly smaller) neighborhood of $0$. It follows that $\ln \frac{1}{z}$ has a pole or a removable singularity at $0$. If this is not evidently absurd already, apply the same to $\ln z=-\ln \frac{1}{z}$ and conclude that the logarithm is a rational function.

Comment: I agree that $ln(\frac{1}{z})$ is not analytic near $z=0$ , has a singularity and is not a rational function.

Comment: But can you show that the multiplicative inverse of a Taylor series ($c_0$ not $0$) is a Taylor series with nonzero radius ?
If so Im willing to accept the answer.

Comment: NVM that last comment. It is clear by substitution using $\frac{1}{1+y}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(z)=\frac1{\frac1z+\text{Log}\frac1z}=\frac z{1+z\,\text{Log}\frac1z}$$

Now,

$$\text{Log}\frac1z:=\log\frac1{|z|}+i\arg\frac1z\implies z\,\text{Log}\frac1z=z\log\frac1{|z|}+iz\arg\frac1z$$

If you now choose a branch cut for the complex logarithm (and you better do if you have any hope to make any sense in this particular stuff), say the usual half negative real axis *and* zero ($\;\Bbb R_-\;$), you get a nice analytic function in the rest (and we don't care what happens with $\,z\to\infty\,$ since we're far away from there) , so

$$z\,\text{Log}\frac1z\xrightarrow[z\to 0\,,\,z\notin\Bbb R_-]{}0$$ and you can talk of a removable singularity of your function at $\,z=0\,$...although this would be a little absurd since you *already removed* this point by choosing the above branch cut for the logarithm, and this will be the situation with any branch cut you choose as *any* of them must contain the zero point...

In short, definitely not analytic there, though...

Comment: So you are saying it is analytic as long as we do not get near the real line ? Did I get that right ? Does that imply that $f(z) + f(-z)$ is analytic ??

Comment: I meant $\,\text{Log}\,z\,$ is analytic, *not* your function. About your function, and doing what is needed, we can talk of a removable singularity there.

Comment: My function has a removable singularity at 0 ? Does that not contradict the other answer given by 75064 ? Doesnt a removable singularity imply that it has a Taylor series such as $\frac{x}{x}$ has Taylor series (at 0) $=1$ ?

Comment: Not in this case since you have no neighbourhood *around* zero to develop a power series there...75064 is right in this, imo.