# When is it justified to approximate a difference equation with its corresponding differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

Consider the difference equation $f_{x+1}-f_x=a(f_x)$ and the differential equation $g'_x=a(g_x)$. When and Why is it justified to say "$f_x - g_x = o(1) $ hence we can solve the difference equation with the differential equation" (not a quote). As an example see the answer I received here where $a:=ln$ .

[An issue with approximations of a recurrence sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374726/an-issue-with-approximations-of-a-recurrence-sequence)

and the comment I gave to it.

Comment: Nobody said that "fx−gx=o(1) hence we can solve the difference equation with the differential equation" in the answer you link to, hence the quotes in the present question are a lie. Since this was already signalled to you, that you keep pretend otherwise is a tad odd.

Comment: I did not say it was said. It was my interpretation.

Comment: Chill man. Im not agressive , you are. Peace.

Comment: Quotes are used for quotations. There is no quotation here. Hence modify your question (and stop pretending people do not answer your questions when they do, or that they write stupid things, simply because you cannot read).

Comment: Ok so you object that $f_x-g_x = o(1)$ but then how does the solution of the differential equation approximate that of the difference equation ? Or if it does not approximate how do you know the proof is valid ? Stop feeling offended , this is a natural question for a beginner.