# Finding the best real value for $C$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, dynamical-systems, recurrence-relations

Consider the recurrence $f_{n+1}=f_n + \ln(f_n)$ with $f_0=2$.
Also consider differential equations of type $g(0)=2$ and $\dfrac{d g}{d x}=\ln(g(x)- C \cdot \ln(g(x)))$. Lets call the solution depending on the real value $C$ as follows : $g_C(x)$.
It has been shown by Did here

[An issue with approximations of a recurrence sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374726/an-issue-with-approximations-of-a-recurrence-sequence)

that the recurrence $f(x)$ lies between $g_1(x)$ and $g_0(x)$. So my question is what is the best value for $0<C<1$ such that $g_C(x)$ is as close to f as can be for large $x$ ?

Comment: Im ok with the $ln$ (if you guys are) but I prefer some space between elements when I multiply them. Not even the $\cdot$ in between them. Thanks for the advice though. But how do I make a space between 2 elements ? Im asking because I have that issue often.

Comment: Since the '$\ln$' has been edited , I assume I should make a note to myself. '\ln' it shall be.